# Bounty answer not worthy of reward

Tags: support, bounty

I have this bountied question: [Bootstrap modal position in WebView UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57025896/bootstrap-modal-position-in-webview-ui) - which received one answer. The answer is poorly worded and coded, and hardly related to the question (bootstrap modal). The answerer also did not follow up when questioned on this.

What should happen in this case?

Comment: An answer needs +2 score to have a chance of getting the auto-award. See [the auto-criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty). If no answer is posted to meet the auto-criteria, and it isn't manually awarded, no one gets the bounty. It will not be refunded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a no-op to me.  Because the answer doesn't meet the auto-award threshold (of a score of +2), and you're not satisfied with it (and I can only presume you would downvote it if it didn't suit your needs), you don't have to do anything.

It's ***unlikely*** that anyone else will swoop in and give it an additional three upvotes to get it over the auto-award threshold at this point.